# (the) best players have little time for other hobbies

Tags: grammar, articles, superlatives

I am wondering, in the following sentence:

> (the) best players have little time for other hobbies.

Should I use the definite article? I am talking about best players in general.

Comment: You'd probably have to change "best" for outstanding or excellent or something.

Comment: @anouk Why? I can say "This is the kind of event you go to with best friends", also with no article.

Comment: @anouk  "best" is perfectly fine in this context.  You might disagree with the intent of the statement, of course, but there's nothing wrong with the grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily, and in this context, *best* is a superlative adjective and superlatives always require the definite article. Other rules about the specificity of a noun aren't important, here.  When you're using a superlative, you use "the."

Better players usually win -> *The best* players usually win
High peaks are harder to climb -> *The highest* peaks are harder to climb
Low valleys are wetter -> *The* lowest valleys are wetter

There are other, idiomatic uses of *best*, in which it's not treated as a superlative, but as an ordinary adjective; for example, *best friends*. This is "idiomatic" in the sense that it evolved from a phrase, or an idea like "my best friend" that is, "my friend who is the best" or maybe "my friend who is the best at being a friend." This grammatical phrase morphed at some point into the not-strictly-grammatical "a best friend."  There are likely other, less common examples where *best* has morphed into a non-superlative adjective, but these are exceptions to the rule.

Comment: But that is not entirely true, see the following textbook examples:  Every class has a best student, They are best friends.. The explanation (not mine): It's a “non-superlative” best that doesn't refer to any definite comparison group.

Comment: @JohnV  I think this answer is fine.  There are various ways "best" can be used (e.g. "best friends") that aren't really *superlatives* as such.  You can say "every class has **a** 'best student'" when talking in general, but when referring to a specific, "**the** best student in the class is Marjorie."

Comment: @Andrew I do not like the statement "Best is a superlative adjective and superlatives always require the definite article", it seems to exclude the cases I mentioned. But I have not down-voted as it just might not be precise enough.

Comment: @JohnV  I'm saying the use of "best" in something like "best friends" is not really as a *superlative*.   It's just a compound idiomatic expression, related to, *"They are the **best** of friends"* -- i.e., their friendship is very strong.  It's possible for someone to have more than one "best friend*".  I suppose this answer can be edited to qualify these cases, but are they really relevant?

Comment: @Andrew Alright, but then the other use (every class has a best student) etc. is using "best", the adjective, but definitely does not require the article because it is used as a non-superlative. All I am saying is that the answer equals "best" with superlatives and thus needing and article.