# ... others suggest that lively colors are (the) best because they make people happier

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article, superlatives

Do we need the 'the' in this sentence?

> While some have argued that pastels are better because they calm
> people down, others suggest that lively colors are (the) best because
> they make people happier.

The task suggests that the 'the' shouldn't be used, but I don't know how to explain it.

How does the use of the article change the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: OR does this answer your question? ["Most" "best" with or without "the".](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/258033/most-best-with-or-without-the) Or [(the) best players have little time for other hobbies.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/208043/the-best-players-have-little-time-for-other-hobbies) Or [Superlative adjectives and adverbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/257975/superlative-adjectives-and-adverbs)

Comment: As suggested by [this NGram,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=colors+are+the+best%2Ccolors+are+best%2Ccolours+are+the+best%2Ccolours+are+best&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccolors%20are%20the%20best%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccolors%20are%20best%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccolours%20are%20the%20best%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccolours%20are%20best%3B%2Cc0) mostly we *wouldn't* include the article in your cited context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you for the links. Unfortunately, I haven't found a relevant answer to my question there. In my example, 'the' is attached to the noun 'colors', and there are no dummy pronouns, but the task marks the use of the article 'the' as a mistake. I know your attitude towards such tasks, but I still decided to ask this question. Is it really wrong to use 'the' is my example?

Comment: It's misleading to suggest that including the article in your specific example is actually "incorrect". It's perfectly grammatical - just ***idiomatically less common***, as can be clearly inferred from the NGram that I linked to in my second comment. If you're looking for a grammatical "rule" as to why this is the case, I'm afraid you won't find one (which is why I personally think it's pretty dumb to include things like that in a "test"). You might not pass your exam if you include "the" in your example, but that's because the *test-setter* is ignorant, not *you.*